# Maximum of column 1 where value of column 2 matches some condition

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have the following in a table :

```
     A   |  B  |  desired_output
   ----------------------------
1 |  10  |  1  |  0
2 |  20  |  7  |  0
3 |  30  |  3  |  0
4 |  20  |  2  |  0
5 |  30  |  5  |  1
```

I'd like to find a formula for each of the cells in the `desired_output` column which looks at the max of B1:B5 but only for rows for which A = max(A1:A5)

If that's not clear, I'll try to put it another way :

```
for all the rows in A1:A5 that are equal to max(A1:A5) // so that's rows 3 and 5
    find the one which has the max value on B // so between B3 and B5, that's B5
        output 1 for this one, 0 for the other
```

I'd say there would be a `where` somewhere if such a function existed, something like `= if(B=(max(B1:B5) where A = max(A1:A5)), 1, 0)` but I can't find how to do it...

---

I can do it in two columns with a trick :

```
     A   |  B  |  C  | D
   ----------------------------
1 |  10  |  1  |     |  0
2 |  20  |  7  |     |  0
3 |  30  |  3  |  3  |  0
4 |  20  |  2  |     |  0
5 |  30  |  5  |  5  |  1
```

With `Cn = if(An=max(A$1:A$5),Bn,"")` and `Dn = if(Cn = max(C$1:C$5), 1, 0)`

But I still can't find how to do it in one column

Comment: so you wanna max of max to be 1 otherwise zero, right?

Comment: What version of Excel? There is a MAXIFS in newer versions.

Comment: I'm actually on google sheets, but I figured the answer would be the same in excel. Google sheets has `maxifs`!

Comment: @François M. Nice question and you've got some good solutions now, but I was wondering if the title could be improved in case people want to search for it? Someting like 'flag maximum of one column conditional on other column being maximum' but not sure how best to phrase it.

Comment: Changed it, what do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
=--AND(A5=MAX($A$1:$A$5),B5=MAXIFS($B$1:$B$5,$A$1:$A$5,MAX($A$1:$A$5)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For systems without MAXIFS, put this in C1 and fill down.

```
=--(B1=MAX(INDEX(B$1:B$5-(A$1:A$5<>MAX(A$1:A$5))*1E+99, , )))
```

Comment: This is clever, even though a bit dirty!

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(CONCAT(A1:A&"×", B1:B),
 JOIN("×", QUERY(A1:B, "order by A desc, B desc limit 1")), 1, 0), )<>"", 1, 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"",N(A:A&"×"&B:B=JOIN("×",SORTN(A:B,1,,1,0,2,0))),))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"",N(A:A&B:B=JOIN(,SORTN(A:B,1,,1,0,2,0))),))
```

Comment: Great insight that OP is really just saying 'sort on A descending then sort on B descending and find match for top record'. I guess there are other possibly shorter options for implementing it e.g. =ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","",--(A:A&"×"&B:B=JOIN("×", sortn(A:B,1,,1,false,2,false)))))

Comment: Or =ArrayFormula(if(A:A<>"",--(A:A&"×"&B:B=JOIN("×", sortn(A:B,1,,1,false,2,false))),)) - I hadn't realised you could put a comma in the if statement and get an empty string! It doesn't work this way in Excel.

Comment: @TomSharpe nice one. and if we play short game then: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"",--(A:A&"×"&B:B=JOIN("×",SORTN(A:B,1,,1,0,2,0))),))` or even `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A:A<>"",--(A:A&B:B=JOIN(,SORTN(A:B,1,,1,0,2,0))),))`

Comment: Absolutely - although you do need the "×" because the last one wouldn't distinguish between (say) 31 3 and 3 13.

Comment: @TomSharpe yeah, but then at least let's save one character position with `N` instead of `--` :)